# Where are the python packages and dependencies located?

Tags: python

creating a package with `Composer`, dependencies are stored in /vendor folder

creating a package with `npm`, dependencies are stored in /node_modules folder

creating a package with `pip`, where are the dependencies stored? and why it's different?

Comment: _"and why it's different ?"_ - Because they are all completely different languages with their own ecosystems.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you so much for answering. now I have understood

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `site-packages` directory documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/install/), but also you can use [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/venv.html) to have per project dependencies.